# Как повернуть стрелку на 180deg в меню select при клике?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На выпадающем списке select при клике нужно повернуть стрелку на 180 градусов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У дефолтного селекта насколько мне известно такой возможности нету. Но можно собрать данную псевдострелку.

```css
.select_wrapp {
  position: relative;
}

.decor_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.75rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(0);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg height='10px' width='10px' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z'/></svg>") no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}


select {

  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

select:focus+.decor_arrow {
  transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="select_wrapp">
  <select name="sel">Choose varible
    <option value="1">Select1</option>
    <option value="2">Select2</option>
  </select>
  <span class="decor_arrow"></span>
</label>
```

Тут есть проблема, что пока фокус на элементе `<select>` стрелка не вращается, но зато этот метод без навешивание JS функций отслеживания.

Comment: немного не то конечно, но интересный способ, спасибо

Comment: по умолчанию стрелку данного элемента не с анимировать... к сожалению. Как и повесить всю эту оббертку на `select:after`

Comment: А можно ли как-то сделать марджины от самого select до его открывающегося списка со значениями ?

Comment: нет, дефолтние элементы `select ` не кастомизируються. Обычно что-то такое делают для смены языка на сайте, но это всё не так реализуеться. Из коробки сместить элементы не выйдет